# how to start running video before completed download in android like youtube?

Tags: android-studio, video, download, youtube

Is it possible to run the video from server after % downloading from server like youtube ? 
sometime we have big file and the user can not wait til completed download.

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: if the video is `.mp4` then make sure the metadata (required to begin playback) is at front of file, not at back end (which happens with some mp4 files). Find a tool called **mp4 fast start** for your OS or use **FFmpeg** if you know it.